# events in android calendar that was added through code does not open

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to add an event on a calendar that i created programmatically like this

```
var uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri; ContentValues val = new ContentValues();

        val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarAccessLevel, CalendarAccess.AccessOwner.ToString());
        val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.Name, "Mary");
        val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.Visible, true);
        val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.SyncEvents, true);
        val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarColor, "0xff00ffff");
        val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarDisplayName, "Mary");
        uri = uri.BuildUpon()
.AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CallerIsSyncadapter, "true")
.AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, AccountName)
.AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CalendarContract.AccountTypeLocal)
.Build();
        var calresult = ContentResolver.Insert(uri, val);

        calID = int.Parse(calresult.LastPathSegment);
        AddCalendarEvent( calID);
```

it gets added successfully and I am able to see this calendar

I am adding event like this,

```
  ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, calID);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "Test Event from M4A");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "This is an event created from Mono for Android");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(2013, 9, 15, 10, 0));
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(2013, 9, 15, 11, 0));

        // GitHub issue #9 : Event start and end times need timezone support.
        // https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/issues/9
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");

        var uri = ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri for new event: {0}", uri);
```

My problem is that when I am trying to open this event to see the description, it gives me an error that "Unfortunately the calendar has stopped". I am able to open the event when it is added to the default calendar. What wrong am I doing in the creating the calendar??
I followed the code from this blog, http://www.derekbekoe.co.uk/blog/16-using-the-android-4-0-calendar-api#part4 and still it is giving me the same error. I am using Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the calendar was not liking the color code set. I used Android.Graphics.Color.Red instead of the hash code for color. It works well with that

Answer (score 0):

When creating the calendar, you should be specifying the OWNER_ACCOUNT. This link from the Android docs shows you the fields that must be included when inserting a new calendar. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html)

This is similarly the case for adding a new event to your calendar. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html)

Also, it is not clear from your code but currently it looks like you are using the default uri for events, *CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri*. You may have to build the event uri also, just like you have done for creating the calendar, and then use this new uri when you insert the event with ContentResolver.Insert.